# How to show that no nontrivial solution of $y''+(1-x^2)y=0$ vanishes infinitaly often.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> How to show that no nontrivial solution of $y''+(1-x^2)y=0$ vanishes infinitely often?

I know that $y''+y=0$  has solution which vanishes infinitely .

But we can  compare $1\geq 1-x^2$ So by strum comparison theorem it must have infinite zero. Where I am missing?

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is a variant of the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem that solutions of
$$
y''+qy=0
$$
can have at most one root in intervals where $q(x)<0$. Thus you get at most one root on $(-\infty,-1)$, a finite number of roots on $[-1,1]$ (as these roots are isolated points in a compact set) and at most one root in $(1,\infty)$.

---

Assume that there are two roots $a<b$ of $y$ with no root in-between and $q<0$ on $(a,b)$. W.l.o.g. assume that $y$ is positive on $(a,b)$, and $y'(a)>0$. Then 
$$
0=y(b)-y(a)=y'(a)(b-a)+\int_a^b(b-x)y''(x)dx=y'(a)(b-a)+\int_a^b(b-x)[-q(x)]y(x)dx>0
$$
which is a contradiction. Thus there is at most one root in $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Could you explain how to prove "a finite number of roots on $[-1, 1]$"?

Comment: First confirm that there can be no intervals of value zero, and no roots with multiplicity for a non-zero solution, this all by the uniqueness theorem. Now that all roots, if any, are isolated, there can only be a finite number in a compact interval.