# Prove that the solutions of the equation $y'' + q(t)y = 0$ are not oscillatory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> More details:
>
> - $t \ge a$
> - The equation is defined in $[a, \infty)$
> - Coefficient $q(t) \in C[a, \infty)$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to\infty}q(t)=l\lt0$
>
> We want to prove that its solutions are not oscillatory in interval $[a,\infty)$.

I'm trying to use the following result, but haven't had any success:

**Proposition**: Consider $q(t)\in C[a, \infty)$ such that $q(t)\ge m\gt0$. Then $x'' + q(t)x = 0$ **is** oscillatory in $[a, \infty)$.

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3092565/115115) should you give some ideas. If not, then please tell us next your definition of "oscillatory" so that there is something definitive to negate.

Comment: See https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-144-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251305-6/S0002-9947-1969-0251305-6.pdf $\qquad$and$\qquad$ https://www.jstor.org/stable/1996149?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents